# Using Jackson Mixins to selectively ignore only provided properties

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following situation:

```java
public class A {
    private String someProperty;
    private String anotherProperty;

    public A() {}

    // getter/setter
```

An `ObjectMapper` configuration as follows (enabled by default, but worth noting to get the point of the question across):

```java
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

and an input JSON that looks as follows:

```java
{
  "someProperty": "someValue",
  "anotherProperty":"anotherValue",
  "unwantedProperty":"unwantedValue"
}
```

When deserializing this JSON using `objectMapper.readValue(bytes, A.class)`, as expected, it gives me an exception:

```java
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "unwantedProperty"
```

Now, what *I want to do*, is the following:

1. Only deserialize properties that are explicitly provided by `A.class`
2. Use a MixIn to ignore all *unwanted, known* properties. So for example, I know that `unwantedProperty` is part of the JSON, but I don't need it, so I want to ignore it.
3. Still raise an `UnrecognizedPropertyException` if a *new, unknown* property suddenly appears in my JSON.

The reason that I wish to use something like a MixIn class for this is that in reality, the input JSON has several dozens of fields. I would prefer not to clutter my `A.class` with dozens and dozens of unused properties with `@JsonIgnore` on them, so that it only contains the fields that I *really* want. If a new property unexpectedly does come along, I want to be forced to have a look at it.

I thought that I could allow this behaviour by using a MixIn as follows:

```java
public abstract class AMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore private String unwantedProperty;
```

together with:

```java
objectMapper.addMixIn(A.class, AMixIn.class);
```

but this seemingly has no effect. I've also tried creating getters in `AMixIn` and giving those `@JsonIgnore`, but this also has no result.

Am I using MixIns incorrectly here? Is what I'm trying to do even possible (as described in the 3 points above)? Or, is there a better way to do this?

I've tried searching, but my use case is a bit esoteric, so I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**
You can instruct Jackson to ignore unknown properties.
I tend to configure the `ObjectMapper` to ignore them,
here is some sample code:

```
private ObjectMapper mapper;
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

// This matches the Fuse Mapper configuration.
builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES
mapper = builder.build();
```

You can also annotate the class to ignore unknown properties.
Here is some sample code:

```
@jsonignoreproperties(ignoreunknown = true)
public class A
{
   ...
```

**Note about question 2:**
In order for the use-mixin-to-ignore-fields-in-json strategy to work,
the fields to be ignored must exist in the class.
In your case,
this means that `class A` must have a field "unwantedProperty" for the mixin to work correctly.

**Direction to solve questions 2 and 3**
You cannot use the MixIn feature of Jackson to solve either
question 2 or question 3.
Instead,
you will need to write a custom deserializer.
I suggest that you also use a custom Jackson annotation
that configures a list of ignored-unrecognized-fields
and have your custom deserializer only throw the exception
for unrecognized fields that are not part of the
ignored-unrecognized-fields list.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. *In order for the use-mixin-to-ignore-fields-in-json strategy to work, the fields to be ignored must exist in the class.* This is the exact piece of knowledge I was missing. I'll be putting a TODO down to implement your proposed solution since I'm OK with the compromise I posted earlier for now, but this was exactly what I was looking for - a custom deserializer would probably perform better too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shows how well I can search; as always, Jackson provides *some* way of doing whatever needs doing. In case it might help someone else:

There exists the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation which, in addition to the `ignoreUnknown` property (that I already knew), supports a list of properties (via `value()`) to ignore during de-/serialization (which I did not know).

This is not *quite* the same as the intended solution above, but having these properties inside of `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ ... })` in the class header instead of the class body is a good enough compromise for me.

So, the solution would be:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"unwantedProperty"})
public class A {
    // same as above...
}
```

Still, if there is a MixIn solution which can completely decouple these things, I'd still like to see it. I'll accept my own answer if nothing comes up in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way documented for using mix-ins I found here:
https://www.grabanotherbyte.com/en/jackson/2020/10/18/jackson-mixins.html

Don't use interfaces for mix-ins but abstract classes for complicated cases. In my case using interfaces did not produce the expected results, but switching to abstract classes gave me more flexibility.